# Control RGB led using microphones, getting the right components

Tags: arduino-uno, rgb-led, audio

Sorry if this is too basic, but I am very new to arduino and electronics. I come from programming, I am trying to start a project where I can control an RGB led strip, I want to be able to control the light intensity and color of the light strip (something like [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HXFKMV6)), using a microphone.

My goal is for frequency to control de color of the rgb light and the dB (Volume) to control the light intensity. I have found several microphones such as [this ones](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00TM7R21W). Can I get both frequency and dB input from this microphones?

Would I need some extra controllers for this project? Again I am very new with this, sorry by the basic questions.

Comment: It would be well worth having a look at [ColorChord](https://github.com/cnlohr/colorchord).

Comment: You are taking on two Arduino projects at the same time (controlling addressable RGB LED strips & frequency discrimination using a microphone).  Judging from past posts here, it would be better if you tried one of your projects first, then post questions about that project before moving on to the to the second.  For instance, many people fail at the RGB LED light strips because of unexpected power supply problems.  And, I am not entirely sure a Arduino Uno can do a good jobs at frequency discrimination.  I do not think it is fast enough to do a good job.

Comment: Thanks @st2000, I will do it that way in the future, if an Arduino-uno is too slow for that would you recommend something else?

Comment: @MarkSmith are you the creator of that program? can I contact you if I have questions about it's use?

Comment: When starting Arduino hacking I find it always best to find someone who's done it before.  @MarkSmith has found you the perfect example project.  I would research it to find out what hardware ColorChord uses.  And don't stop at the GIT web page, the ColorChord guy (I think Charles is his name) had made several YouTube.com videos the show off his work.

Comment: @MarkSmith you should flesh out your comment and make it the answer.  Derek, you should accept his answer and complete this question / answer entry into the arduino stackexchange website.

Comment: No, I'm afraid I'm not the creator. As @st2000 says, the guy who is has some fascinating projects - I've wasted, er, spent hours watching his youTube stuff. Really worth diving into. ColorChord uses an ESP8266 which is a great little device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be worth checking out the [ColorChord](https://github.com/cnlohr/colorchord) project.  It runs on an ESP8266, not an Arduino, but it ought to get you going.